# Xamarin UWP: Video Player components dont seem to work with Compile with .NET Native tool chain turned on

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

Video player libraries doesnt seem to work when ran with UWP with flag "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" turned on. Has anyone found a way to make them work with native?

Same data on debug mode and store environment.

I've tried two different video player libraries now, so I know its not the library and something to do with UWP Compile with .NET Native tool chain flag.

No exceptions or anything, just blank screen.

Comment: Try enable .NET Native tool chain understand debug mode and see what report from your app. It's also black box to us about what you are doing. To understand more we have to debug it.

Comment: I had to reference the video component renderer in the app.cs assemblies and now it works for .net native tool chain.

Comment: @PizzHead Glad to know that. Do you mind to create an answer and close this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reference the video component renderer in the app.cs assemblies and now it works for .net native tool chain.